# Program get stuck after scanf() function

Tags: c

I am required to create a program which requires user to input the new born baby by implementing structure. However, after printing the message of "father age" for asking user to input the age, the program straight away terminated itself. Why is it happened and how to solve it?

[image: Output of the code]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct father{
    char dad_name[50];
    int dad_age;
};
struct mother{
    char mom_name[50];
    int mom_age;
};
struct baby{
    char baby_name[50];
    char sex[6];
    char birthday[10];

    struct father father1;
    struct mother mother1;
};

struct baby *b1;
void display(int);

int main(){
    int baby_num;

    printf("Enter number of baby that is/are going to input: ");
    scanf("%d", &baby_num);

    display(baby_num);

    printf("\nNEW BORN IN KUANTAN HOSPITAL\n");
    for(int i=0; i<baby_num; i++){
        printf("\nBaby %d\n", i+1);
        printf("Baby Name: %s\n", b1[i].baby_name);
        printf("Sex: %s\n", b1[i].sex);
        printf("Birthday: %s\n", b1[i].birthday);
        printf("\nFather name: %s\n", b1[i].father1.dad_name);
        printf("Father age: %d", b1[i].father1.dad_age);
        printf("\nMother name: %s\n", b1[i].mother1.mom_name);
        printf("Mother age: %s\n", b1[i].mother1.mom_age);
    };
    return 0;
};

void display(int baby_num){
    int temp;

    b1 = (struct baby*) malloc(baby_num * sizeof(struct baby));
    for(int i=0; i<baby_num;i++){
        printf("Baby Name: ");
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        scanf("%[^\n]", b1[i].baby_name);
        printf("Sex: ");
        scanf("%s", b1[i].sex);
        printf("Birthday: ");
        scanf(" %s", b1[i].birthday);
        printf("Father name: ");
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        scanf("%[^\n]", b1[i].father1.dad_name);
        printf("Father age: ");
        scanf("%d", b1[i].father1.dad_age);
        printf("Mother name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", b1[i].mother1.mom_name);
        printf("Mother age: ");
        scanf(" %d", b1[i].mother1.mom_age);
    };
}
```

Comment: `struct baby *b1;` is just an unitialised pointer.

Comment: Aside. `scanf("%[^\n]", b1[i].baby_name);` will need a space before `%` so `scanf(" %49[^\n]", b1[i].baby_name);`

Comment: Also `scanf(" %d", b1[i].mother1.mom_age);` needs to be `scanf(" %d", &b1[i].mother1.mom_age);`. The big problem, is that you are writing too much code before testing any of it. Write one line, then test it. Write another line, thne test it.

Comment: Also, you are printing `mom_age` as if it was a string, but it's an int.

Comment: @WeatherVane it gets initialized inside `display` function. The decision is debatable, but it's not UB.

Comment: Calling the input function `display()` is misleading.

Answer (score -1):

in display function, for father's age and mother's age, you need to send scanf function wrong value.

```
scanf("%d", &(b1[i]).father1.dad_age);
```

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: you are right, sorry. edited.